# how to know the type of sql query result before it is executed in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

As far as I know, there exists no such features that gives the expected type of query result in sql without executing the query. However, I think that it's possible to implement and there could be some tricks for it.

I'm using sqlalchemy, so I hope that the solution is easy to implement with sqlalchemy. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean, "type"? Insert, update etc. ?

Comment: I mean type of return value of query. For example, "select user.age form user" returns records of integer. I want to know that it's integer before executing the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get column types from [column_descriptions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.column_descriptions)

```
[c['type'] for c in query.column_descriptions]
```

Or if you need to know Python types:

```
[c['type'].python_type for c in query.column_descriptions]
```